# C++ zero initialization without constructor

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, initialization

I don't understand what happens regarding the zero initialization of structs that has default values for its members.

If I have these structs:

```cpp
struct A {
  int *a;
  int b;
};

struct B {
  int *a;
  int b;
  B() : b(3) {}
};

struct C {
  int *a;
  int b = 3;
};
```

What we can say without a doubt is:

- `A a;` leaves all fields uninitialized
- `A a{};` is {nullptr, 0}
- `B b;` and `B b{};` both are {garbage, 3} (the constructor is called)

Now it's unclear what happens when I do the following, here are the results using gcc:

```cpp
C c; // {garbage, 3}
C c{}; // {nullptr, 3}
```

The question is: does `C c{};` *guarantees* that `C::a` is initialized to `nullptr`, in other words, does having default members like in `C` still zero initialize the other members if I explicitly construct the object like `C c{};`?

Because it's not what happens if I have a constructor that does the same thing than `C` (like in `B`), the other members are *not* zero initialized, but why? What is the difference between `B` and `C`?

Comment: ot: I guess its me being pedantic, but the term "garbage" is a complete misnomer here. There is no garbage. Its an indeterminate value. You have no way to see that value without breaking the rules of the language (undefined behavior), if you do so it might appear as garbage but it isnt.

Comment: just mentioning it because that "garbage myth" makes it sometimes difficult to discuss outcomes of such experiments: In fact you cannot tell the difference between `3` or `nullptr` and "garbage", because if your code has undefined behavior there is no guarantee that you get wrong / unexpected output

Comment: The answer has changed between C++11 and C++14. In C++11, `C` is not an aggregate, and list initialization calls an implicitly-defined constructor that does not initialize `a`. In C++14, `C` is an aggregate, and list initialization zero-initializes all members that aren't given a value in the *brace-init* list nor by an initializer specified in the member declaration. `B` is not an aggregate either way, due to the user-defined constructor.

Comment: Related article: [the fickle aggregate](https://dfrib.github.io/the-fickle-aggregate/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of C++14, `C` is an aggregate (like `A`), and `C c{}` syntax performs aggregate initialization. This includes, in part:

> **[dcl.init.aggr]/8** If there are fewer *initializer-clauses* in the list than there are elements in a non-union aggregate, then each element not explicitly initialized is initialized as follows:
> (8.1) — If the element has a default member initializer (12.2), the element is initialized from that initializer.
> (8.2) — Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list (11.6.4).
> (8.3) — Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

So `C c{};` is equivalent to `C c{{}, 3};`. Initializing an `int*` member with empty list causes it to be zero-initialized.

In C++11, `C` is not an aggregate (having a default member initializer was disqualifying), and `C c{};` calls an implicitly-defined constructor that leaves `c.a` member uninitialized.

In all versions of the standard, `B` is not an aggregate due to the user-defined constructor. `B b{};` calls that constructor, which explicitly initializes `b` member and chooses to leave `a` uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

[Aggregate initialization - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

> - If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members are [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed.
>
> (until C++11)
>
> - If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members and bases (since C++17) or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members and bases (since C++17) are initialized by their [default member initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization), if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14) copy-initialized from empty lists, in accordance with the usual [list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates). If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed.
>
> (since C++11)

So `A a{};` all members are default initialized